# How can I get past 3.5 stars in The Sims 1, super star EP

Tags: the-sims

In The Sims 1, there's an expansion pack where you can be a star. And no matter what you do, you can never get past the 3.5 star points. I always get stuck at the photo sessions level. And the photographer won't like the photo shots ever, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can dig up:

- Go out in public often
- Engage with other stars and (more importantly) befriend them. Befriending them gives extra points
- Marry a celebrity, this will give you quite a few points in the process.

Source: [Sims Wikia on celebrity status](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Celebrity_status)